# Which is secure cipher suites for TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl

We have implemented TLS 1.2 on SERVER 2019, how can we know the best chiper suite used for IIS 10.
Please, someone, give me Priority Order would be great for me.

Comment: You don't. You let the server decide among those that are supported by both the client and the server. Off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no "best" or "most secure" cipher suite you can use in all cases. Generally, when chosing a ciphersuite you want to support, you follow some principles to come up with a suitable cipher suite for your use case. Some of those are:

- Chose ciphers which are supported by both your server and your intended clients
- Eliminate insecure ciphers (e.g. cryptographically broken ones or ciphers with too small key sizes)
- Performance considerations (ECDSA is faster than RSA but not supported everywhere, longer key sizes are (significantly) slower than smaller keysizes but are more secure, ...)
- forward secrecy
- ...

If you don't want to deal with the propertyies of all the affected ciphers, there is a config generator maintained by Mozilla which can generate secure configurations for a variety of webservers for one of three security profiles at

https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

You still need to decide based on the clients you intend to support and their supported ciphers which security profile is suitable.

An updated description of the available profiles along with some reasoning for the chosen options is available at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS

To check your server and top get an overview about which browsers are able to connect to it, you could use the Qualys SSL Server Test at  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/